# Why is the moderator diamond so big?

Tags: bug, design

If you take a look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1DPw.png)

[image]

you'll notice that the badge is much bigger than the username itself (and it is a joke but used to hide the actual name). I have also noticed that the diamond is a bigger font size than the username as well.

I'd suggest we just keep it the same size as the username.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/176715/moderator-diamond-is-too-large-relative-to-other-text-on-android

Comment: Appears to be by design: `font-weight: bold; font-size: 140%;`

Comment: @DragonLord Not necessarily, since that's for android. I'm on Windows.

Comment: @DragonLord are you running windows also?

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows.

Comment: Hmm. so I guess they're not gonna change htis, eh? @DragonLord

Comment: Where exactly are you a mod? ;p

Comment: Nowhere T_T But in my dreams, I am the mod of everything....lol no i have a lief. i think @JourneymanGeek

Comment: Are you using a different font than the default one?

Comment: @Player72 - Dragonlord isn't even a moderator.  This sounds like a http://meta.stackexchange.com/ question

Comment: @Ramhound however the huge diamond does not appear on SO, and it is normal on there.